# Unable to update data in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have Json structure like below

```
{
    "organizationId" : 339975,
    "domains" : [
        {       
        "application" : "ABC",
         "activeInd": true,
         "subdomain":[
                      {"url":"URL1",
                       "clientName":"ABCClient"
                      }
                        ]
         },
        {       
        "application" : "mno",
         "activeInd": false,
         "subdomain":[
                      {"url":"URL2",
                       "clientName":"MNOClient"
                      }
                     ]
         },
        {       
        "application" : "pqr",
         "activeInd": false,
         "subdomain":[
                      {"url":"URL3",
                       "clientName":"pqrClient"
                      }
                     ]
         },
        {       
        "application" : "egh",
         "activeInd": true,
         "subdomain":[
                      {"url":"URL4",
                       "clientName":"eghClient"
                      }
                     ]
         }]
}
```

when I tried to run the below query

```
var dataToUpdate =  "updatedUrl3"
db.orgConfigData.update(
    { "organizationId" : 339975,domains: { $elemMatch: { "application" : "pqr" } }},
            { $set: { 'domains.$[elemx].subdomain.url': dataToUpdate } },
            {"arrayFilters":[
                {
                    "elemx.url":"URL3"
                }]}
       
            )
```

I'm unable to update data in MongoDB, It gives results like below.

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 1,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0
})
```

I understand that it is able to find the match but not updating the data, can someone help me to find an effective method to use it and get the output(get it updated).

I need the output like below once I run the query

```
{
    "organizationId" : 339975,
    "domains" : [
        {       
        "application" : "ABC",
         "activeInd": true,
         "subdomain":[
                      {"url":"URL1",
                       "clientName":"ABCClient"
                      }
                        ]
         },
        {       
        "application" : "mno",
         "activeInd": false,
         "subdomain":[
                      {"url":"URL2",
                       "clientName":"MNOClient"
                      }
                     ]
         },
        {       
        "application" : "pqr",
         "activeInd": false,
         "subdomain":[
                      {"url":"updatedUrl3",
                       "clientName":"pqrClient"
                      }
                     ]
         },
        {       
        "application" : "egh",
         "activeInd": true,
         "subdomain":[
                      {"url":"URL4",
                       "clientName":"eghClient"
                      }
                     ]
         }]
}
```

Comment: If you add the full query we maybe able to help ... :)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the Question [Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your update command. Please provide it as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have updated the details Hope this help solve the query

Comment: The update refers to `subdomains` but the sub-documents in the array have `subdomain`.  Perhaps a simple typo?

Comment: Oh yeah i have update it now Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rkNvb7ks17o)

example:

```
 db.orgConfigData.update({
   "organizationId": 339975
 },
 {
   $set: {
     "domains.$[elemx].subdomain.$[elemy].url": "updatedUrl3"
   }
    },
    {
  "arrayFilters": [
   {
  "elemx.application": "pqr"
   },
   {
    "elemy.url": "URL3"
   }
  ]
})
```

explained:

1. Filter the organizationId: 339975 documents in the query part of update query
2. Set the value only for the filtered elements located via the two arrayFilters defined as elemx & elemy